# Error when fitting the scipy.stats.erlang distribution

Tags: python, scipy

I'm new to this, but I have some data that I am trying to fit to various distributions.

Right now I'm just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is an example.

```
data = np.array([-0.00363649,  0.00329399,  0.00648754, -0.00115784, 
                 -0.00020446, -0.0223319])

scipy.stats.erlang.fit(data)
```

This returns the warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: The shape parameter of the erlang distribution has been given a non-integer value 2.1.
RuntimeWarning: The shape parameter of the erlang distribution has been given a non-integer value 1.9.
.
.
.
```

It does this a lot of times starting with 2.1 and then descending. I'm a little confused about what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) has an integer shape parameter.  Other than that, it is the same the [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

The SciPy implementation of the Erlang distribution is basically the same as the gamma distribution, but it generates a warning when you give a non-integer value for the shape parameter.  The `fit` method of the SciPy distributions does not do discrete optimization, so it will pass non-integer values to the Erlang distribution methods, and that results in the warnings.

To avoid this, use the [gamma distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) instead of the Erlang distribution.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that it has to do with how the _fitstart method goes about things. I am having kind of a hard time getting around the documentation, so thanks for the pointer.